# MySQL: Subtract two values in rows in table A for each member in table B

Tags: mysql, sql

I have written this code in Java and want to know if i can do it more efficiently in a SQL statement.

I have two tables. One holds member's data, the other holds their measurements.

```
Members
 ID  | Name
 ----------
 001 | Mary
 002 | Jane
 003 | Anne


Measurements
  idMember | date       |  weight
  -------------------------------
  001      | 2013-06-21 |  65
  002      | 2013-06-23 |  68
  003      | 2013-06-21 |  75
  001      | 2013-09-20 |  64
  002      | 2013-06-21 |  70
  001      | 2014-01-18 |  62
  003      | 2013-06-21 |  74
  002      | 2013-06-21 |  69
```

What I need to be able to do is to find a total amount of weight lost (or gained).

This means looking at each member and subtracting the last measurement from the first and then summing the total.

Thanks!

Comment: why do you need the Members table? What output columns do you expect? And, BTW, what have you tried?

Comment: can you write your wished result in table ?

Comment: the fact that you can have more measurements on the same date makes things more complicated

Comment: Do you have an auto increment in the measurements table?

Comment: You need to either add the date and time of the recording to the table or create an effective sequence field for multiple measurements on the same day. It is impossible to tell which measurement came first.

Comment: Also the total amount of weight lost and gained throughout time (each #, both the amount lost, and amount gained, gross) or just the overall net amount as a gain or loss?

Comment: please have a look at the discussion with @ShWiVeL in my answer and please clarify how the measurements on the same day should be handled. In your data there is no information about the order of measurements on the same day. (Unfortunately I have to go to bed now)

Comment: @Watler Tross - Need the members table as one member can have many measurements. It will never happen that the same member has more than one measurement on the same date. Even if they did, one would expect them to weigh the same ;-)

Comment: @echo_Me yes the results can be in a table

Comment: @Mihai - the table have been simplified for this example. Measurements has an auto increment id field

Comment: @ShWiVel - I simplified the table too much. The date is actually a timestamp field. At the end of the day it should be a net amount. What  I need is a figure of how many kilos all the members in the gym as a whole have lost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select sum(s0.w - s1.w) as total_weight_loss
from (select idMember, max(weight) as w from Measurements m
      where m.date = (select min(date)  from Measurements n
                      where m.idMember = n.idMember)
      group by idMember) s0
join (select idMember, min(weight) as w from Measurements m
      where m.date = (select max(date)  from Measurements n
                      where m.idMember = n.idMember)
      group by idMember) s1
on s0.idMember = s1.idMember
```

**EDIT**

SInce it turned out that there also is a Measurements.ID, all difficulties related to the handling of the measurements on the same date can be avoided altogether like this:

```
select sum(s0.w - s1.w) as total_weight_loss
from (select idMember, weight as w from Measurements m
      where m.ID = (select min(ID) from Measurements n
                    where m.idMember = n.idMember)) s0
join (select idMember, weight as w from Measurements m
      where m.ID = (select max(ID) from Measurements n
                    where m.idMember = n.idMember)) s1
on s0.idMember = s1.idMember
```

Comment: So this assumes a person weighs more later in the day, for their first reading, and assumes a person weighs the least later in the day, for the last reading.

Comment: No, it assumes that a higher outcome is more desirable ;-) The output is the sum of the differences between the max weight on the first day and the min weight on the last day

Comment: Right but given that he wants it chronologically (granted, he doesn't have sufficient data to make the determination), you're essentially saying that for the first day, the highest weight was later in the day, and for the last day, the opposite is true, that the lowest weight occurred last.

Comment: @ShWiVeL, I don't see what you say in my query. I don't assume that.

Comment: In your own words, "The output is the sum of the differences between the max weight on the first day and the min weight on the last day". So you do make assumptions about what measurement came first based on whether the weight is higher or lower.

Comment: @ShWiVeL: actually I don't, I simply choose the weights that maximize the output. If the task had been to subtract the first measurement on the first day from the last measurement on the last day, you would be partially right, except that for the first day, I would assume the highest weight to come from the first measurement of the day

Comment: Your words: "If the task had been to subtract the first measurement on the first day from the last measurement on the last day, you would be partially right" His words "subtracting the last measurement from the first" I guess that was the task. And yes, I reversed your assumption for the first day, although it is still an assumption.

Comment: @ShWiVeL, I interpreted the OP's words as "subtracting the measurement of the last day from the measurement of the first day" - of course, WHICH measurement of these days? I chose the most "optimistic" answer, and also the correct answer if people were kind of abstract and would loose weight monotonically

Comment: You are not quoting what he said. He did not use the word "day" he just said the first and the last. The first measurement would be the first measurement occurring on the first day. That is implied. Unfortunately we do not know how to tell which one was first, on the first day, nor which was last, on the last day.

Comment: Sorry not too have joined in this conversation earlier but it was midnight in my timezone when I wrote the question. I didn't notice that I has added a measurement for the same member on the same day. As I mentioned above, it is unlikely to happen and even if it did, the few hundred grammes is not going to influence the total amount in any significant way. That said, I also simplified the table too much as there is also a time field.

Comment: So Walter you nailed it. Many thanks! Now you have to explain it!! :-)

Comment: How would you edit it if you were to add a time field?

Comment: @CraigMorgan, I think you should not have a separate time field, but simply have one datetime field, holding date and time. Anyway, since you have a Measurements.ID, I edited my answer to use that one for the query. I have to run now, improvements to my answer will have to wait a bit :-(

Comment: You're absolutely right, but I am trying to pull statistical data out of a legacy system so I would have to write a script to combine the two fields first. The question is, what's easier?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
select members.name,
       curr.date as curr_date,
       curr.weight as curr_weight,
       prev.weight as prev_weight,
       curr.weight - prev.weight as weight_change
  from members
  join measurements curr
    on members.id = curr.idmember
  join measurements prev
    on members.id = prev.idmember
 where prev.date = (select max(x.date)
                      from measurements x
                     where x.idmember = prev.idmember
                       and x.date < curr.date)
```

SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c16123/7/0

Comment: @WalterTross that's just because the alias on the 2nd join was "curr" but should have been "prev". I added a sql fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  select name, sum(t2.w - t1.w) as weight_changes,if(sum(t2.w - t1.w)<0,concat('Lost ',ABS(sum(t2.w - t1.w)),' Kg'),concat('Gained ',ABS(sum(t2.w - t1.w)),' Kg')) status
  from (select idMember, max(weight) as w from Measurements m
  where m.date = (select min(date)  from Measurements n
                  where m.idMember = n.idMember)
  group by idMember) t1
  join (select idMember, min(weight) as w from Measurements m
  where m.date = (select max(date)  from Measurements n
                  where m.idMember = n.idMember)
  group by idMember) t2
  on t1.idMember = t2.idMember
  join Members ON Members.id = t1.idMember
   Group by t1.idMember
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/52cf7/8)

Comment: does not work if on an intermediate day a person weighs more than on the first day or less than on the last day